# need to perform validations on file in s3 and copy it to two different tables

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I want to validate file in s3 and send all valid and invalid data to two different tables in redshift. Can anyone help out with an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the file from S3 using `PERMISSIVE` mode. On this mode, Spark will create an extra column `_corrupt_record` that will contain information about the problem found for the specific row. Then you can filter by that column to separate the dataframe as valid and invalid data.

```
data = """{"a": 1, "b":2, "c":3}|{"a": 1, "b":2, "c":3}|{"a": 1, "b, "c":10}""".split('|')

# Valid data 
validDF = (spark.read
  .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")
  .option("columnNameOfCorruptRecord", "_corrupt_record")
  .json(sc.parallelize(data))
  .filter(col("_corrupt_record").isNull())
)

display(validDF)

# Invalid data 
invalidDF = (spark.read
  .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")
  .option("columnNameOfCorruptRecord", "_corrupt_record")
  .json(sc.parallelize(data))
  .filter(col("_corrupt_record").isNotNull())
)

display(invalidDF)
```

If you want to save the DataFrames into a Redshift table you can do as follow:

```
preactions = "TRUNCATE schema.table_name"
# Load the data into Redshift    
validDF.write\
            .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift")\
            .option("url", db_redshift_url)\
            .option("user", user)\
            .option("password", password)\
            .option("dbtable", "schema.table_name")\
            .option("aws_iam_role", redshift_copy_role)\
            .option("tempdir", args["TempDir"])\
            .option("preactions", preactions)\
            .mode("append")\
            .save()
```

The above code should write the DataFrame into Redshift and you can use it inside an AWS Glue Spark job. No need to use psycopg2.

Comment: thank you Aida!can I use this example in glue job??whenever I run a glue job using python or pyspark I have an issue with libraries like psycopg2,pandas.I just downloaded a zip file of libraries and uploaded into s3, given the s3 path of libraries to glue job but it still throwing me an error "no module found".I stucked with this from past week.Can you help me to sort it out.

Comment: @NaveenKadiyala You can use the code above in AWS Glue Spark jobs (Python) but not pandas code. Pandas is not supported on the Spark jobs but it's on AWS Glue Python Shells jobs. Regarding psycopg2, I don't think you really need it. What do you want to do with it?

Comment: @AidaMartinez i want send the two valid and invalid tables to redshift and i think psycopg2 is the module which is used to connect  redshift.please correct me if iam wrong!!u can see the phyton shell job whicch i used to run in glue below

Comment: import psycopg2
def redshift():
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='XX', host="endpoint",port='5439', user='usename', password='passwd')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tablename;")
    cur.execute(
        "create table a();")
    cur.execute("begin;")
    cur.execute("copy public.tablename from 's3://bucketname/sample.csv' credentials 'aws_access_key_id=XXXX ;aws_secret_access_key=XXX' csv;")
   cur.execute("commit;")
    print("Copy executed fine!")
redshift()        ##the code above is used to connect redshift in python shell job

Comment: @NaveenKadiyala see an update on my response above. That code will work with AWS Glue Spark jobs but not with Python Shell.